# powershell script to format input linkfield

Tags: powershell, sitecore

Sitecore ISE throws exception when I try to input sitecore linkfield Raw value.

```
$faqLinkItem.XXXX= <link text "" anchor="" id = {"1234-xxxx-"}/>"
```

Error:
The string is missing the terminator: ".
Of type: System.Management.Automation.ParseException

Comment: code sinppet:$faqLinkItem.XXXX= <link text "" anchor=""  id = {"1234-xxxx-"}/>"

Comment: Have you tried escaping the quotes (https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html)?

Comment: You are ending the whole line with a double-quote character, but that seems to be stand-alone (there's no accompanying second quote for that). Shouldn't it rather be `$faqLinkItem.XXXX= '<link text "" anchor="" id = {"1234-xxxx-"}/>'` ?

Comment: hello guys, got format issue sorted out. It worked, updated the sitecore raw field

[System.String]::Concat("<", "link ",  "text=",'""',   " anchor="""" ",   "linktype=",'""',   " class="""" ","title="""" ","querystring="""" ", "id=",'"{}"',"/>")